# Excel to pdf in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook named as "Billing Sheet". in that workbook, sheet1 have inputs and i want sheet output in sheet2.and i need to extract the output sheet as pdf file.
if i have 10 rows in sheet1 means i want the output as 10 pdf files.

i am not expert in VBA.I have created the code for Sheet2. 
query : My Do while loop is not ending. Please help me

```
Sub test()
startrow = 2
'On Error GoTo errHandler
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("D2").Select
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
i = 2

Do While startrow <= lastrow


 a = Range("D2").Row
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value = "" Or Sheets("sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value = " " Then
 Selection.End(xlDown).Select

 a = ActiveCell.Row

End If

'' Vendor Name(D1)

 If Sheets("sheet1").Range("D1").Value = "Vendor Name" Then
    Sheets("sheet2").Range("A3").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("D" & a).Value
End If

''' Address 1

If Sheets("sheet1").Range("E1").Value = "Address 1" Then
    Sheets("sheet2").Range("A4").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("E" & a).Value

End If

''' Address 2
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("F1").Value = "Address 2" Then
 Sheets("sheet2").Range("A5").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("F" & a).Value
End If

''' Address 3
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("G1").Value = "Address 3" Then
 Sheets("sheet2").Range("A6").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("G" & a).Value
End If

''' Address 4
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("H1").Value = "Address 4" Then
 Sheets("sheet2").Range("A7").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("H" & a).Value
End If

''' Address 5
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("I1").Value = "Address 5" Then
 Sheets("sheet2").Range("A8").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("I" & a).Value
End If

''' Address 6
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("J1").Value = "Address 6" Then
 Sheets("sheet2").Range("A9").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("J" & a).Value
End If

''' Bill to Department
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("M1").Value = "Bill to Department" Then
 Sheets("sheet2").Range("E3").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("M" & a).Value
'Sheets("sheet2").Range("E3").Select
'Selection.Font.Bold = True
End If

''' Bill To
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("N1").Value = "Bill To" Then
 Sheets("sheet2").Range("E4").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("N" & a).Value

End If

''' Bill to Address 1
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("O1").Value = "Bill to Address 1 " Then
 Sheets("sheet2").Range("E5").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("O" & a).Value
' Range("E5").Select
End If

''' Bill to Address 2
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("P1").Value = "Bill to Address 2" Then
 Sheets("sheet2").Range("E6").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("P" & a).Value

End If


''' Bill to Address 3
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("Q1").Value = "Bill to Address 3" Then
 Sheets("sheet2").Range("E7").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("Q" & a).Value

End If

''' Bill to Address 4
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("R1").Value = "Bill to Address 4" Then
 Sheets("sheet2").Range("E8").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("R" & a).Value

End If

''' Bill to Address 5
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("S1").Value = "Bill to Address 5" Then
 Sheets("sheet2").Range("E9").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("S" & a).Value

End If

''' Bill to Address 6
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("T1").Value = "Bill to Address 6" Then
 Sheets("sheet2").Range("E10").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("T" & a).Value

End If

''' Phone No.
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("U1").Value = "Phone No." Then

 Sheets("sheet2").Range("E11").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("U1").Value
Sheets("sheet2").Range("F11").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("U" & a).Value
End If

''' FAX No.
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("V1").Value = "Fax No." Then

 Sheets("sheet2").Range("E12").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("V1").Value
Sheets("sheet2").Range("F12").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("V" & a).Value
End If

''' VAT Reg. No.
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("W1").Value = "VAT Reg. No. " Then

 Sheets("sheet2").Range("E13").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("W1").Value
Sheets("sheet2").Range("F13").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("W" & a).Value
End If

''' Bank
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("X1").Value = "Bank" Then

 Sheets("sheet2").Range("E14").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("X1").Value
Sheets("sheet2").Range("F14").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("X" & a).Value
End If


''' Bank Branch
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("Y1").Value = "Bank Branch" Then

 Sheets("sheet2").Range("E15").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("Y1").Value
Sheets("sheet2").Range("F15").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("Y" & a).Value
End If

''' Account No.
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("Z1").Value = "Account No." Then

Sheets("sheet2").Range("E16").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("Z1").Value
Sheets("sheet2").Range("F16").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("Z" & a).Value
End If





i = i + 1


Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: I beleive you meant to do `Do While i <= lastrow`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do. just looking at your code I can only advise you to use "Option Explicit" on top of you module. Which will force you to declare variables.(a good way of learning VBA). Regarding your question  **"My Do while loop is not ending. Please help me"**

if you are using a blind loop have a safety trigger/max_round mechanism or use fixed round loops like for..next. or at least make sure your condition will definitely met at some points.

in your loop the condition is "startrow <= lastrow" this will always be true hence your loop is not finishing. **"i/current_row <= lastrow"** would be a more logical condition.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim startRow As Long
Dim I As Long

For I = startRow To lastRow
    'do your operation here.. use I as current row/counter
Next I
```